# Where do I go for bodily injury claims against StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

Unicoin mining has damaged my wrist and possibly my psyche. I believe a legal claim can be made that mining unicoins makes us de facto employees and entitles us to workers compensation.

Also, NEED MORE UNICOINS.

Comment: I have been waiting for a carpel tunnel complaint... err report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mail your complaint to Unicorntopia Labor Organization, at 777 Unicorn Street, Rainbow District, Greenfield City, Unicorntopia. Your claim will be resolved in 6-8 weeks.

Other methods of contact:

- Fax (thanks to Anna Lear for reminding): **1-900-UNICORN**
- Email: **contact@labor.unicorn.org.unc**

Comment: Do you have a fax number? I'm too technologically advanced for *mail*.

Comment: @Geobits 1-900-UNICORN. First page is free, subsequent pages are charged at 10 unicoins per character. Additional carrier charges may apply.

Comment: @AnnaLear Disappointed that calling that number didn't give me a nostalgic fax tone :(

Comment: @nhahtdh: Anna Lear's number is a 900 (premium) number, not an 800 (toll-free) number. ;-)